# How do we compute homology from the nerve $\text{Nrv}(\Sigma)$ for $\Sigma=\{S^n,\dots,S^n\}$ covering the CW complex $M$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, computational-mathematics, computational-geometry

Suppose a CW complex $M$ is given by the union of $n$-spheres, namely $M=\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}S^n$, without knowledge of intersections. The only requirement is that the union covers $M$. Let $\Sigma=\{S^n,\dots,S^n\}$ be a finite collection of sets, with cardinality $|A|$. The nerve consists of all subcollections
whose sets have a non-empty common intersection, $\text{Nrv}(\Sigma)=\left\{X\subseteq\Sigma\big|\bigcap X\ne\emptyset\right\}$, which is an abstract simplicial complex. The nerve should look something like this (e.g. a Čech complex): [image]

That is, we are allowed to arrange the spheres in a configuration of our choosing, so long as the configuration still covers $M$. (Indeed, we can "pull" the spheres apart as much as possible so that they still cover $M$-an optimal configuration-with the least amount of spheres used).

> How do we compute homology groups $H_k(M;\mathbb{Z})$ from the nerve $\text{Nrv}(\Sigma)$ for $\Sigma=\{S^n,\dots,S^n\}$ covering the CW complex $M$?

*Idea*: Since we need some information on intersections, suppose we construct the following *optimal configuration*. Begin with two $n$-spheres attached at a base point, namely $S^n\vee S^n$. Then construct two other $n$-spheres that pass through the intersection point of $S^n\vee S^n$. Finally, we continue the process by constructing other spheres $S^n$ that pass through the intersection "points" of other spheres. We write "points" realizing that the intersection of two $n$-spheres is actually an $(n-1)$-sphere. The *points* we refer to are those corresponding to the two intersections in the $S^2$ orthographic projection onto a plane. We can of course vary the radius of the sphere under this construction.

---

As mentioned by Mike Miller, the condition we want is that the $k$-fold intersections, for $k$ sufficiently large, are all empty or contractible. Then the Čech complex of this cover (with constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$) recovers the homology of the manifold. The general case where $k$-fold intersections are not contractible instead takes the form of a spectral sequence involving cohomology of the various intersections. I am not sure, however, how to make this mathematically precise.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean closed/open balls instead of spheres ?

Comment: No, I do mean spheres. I just mentioned the Čech complex because it is similar. @NicholasHemelsoet

Comment: Ok. Can you give me an example of a connected manifold covered by copies of $S^n$ which is not homeomorphic to $S^n$ ?

Comment: Is $\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}S^n$ homeomorphic to $S^n$? I could change the requirement that $M$ is a manifold to just topological space if that changes anything. @Nicholashemelsoet

Comment: I think so. If two spheres $S_1, S_2$ intersect non trivially (that is if $S_1 \cap S_2$ is not empty, and not equal to $S_1$) then $M$ is not a manifold.

Comment: Yes, typically a CW-complex works I think.

Comment: Honestly, something about this question sounds like barking up a wrong tree or making your life unnecessarily difficult. If you want to compute homology of a CW complex, a standard procedure is to compute cellular homology of a chosen CW presentation. Is there a good example one can sink one's teeth into, which would explain why this utterly standard procedure isn't a good idea, or why you want to do it this other way? Is there a reason you want to avoid using homology of the nerve of a good open cover, and instead get your hands dirty with a complicated spectral sequence? Context, motivation!

Comment: No, I would like to use homology of the nerve for an open cover-I just don't know how to in this case. @user43208

Comment: Okay. Out of curiosity, is there a concrete example whose homology you want to compute? (And by the way, are you familiar with cellular homology? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_homology)

Comment: Yes, I would like to find the homology of this cover (with non-empty intersection). The number of $n$-spheres can be made to be infinite so I am sure a nerve can be constructed using some "optimal cover". (And, yes I am familiar with cellular homology, especially for $S^n$, although I am not too sure how to use it when considering a union as given above.) @user43208

Comment: I don't think we're communicating well. A CW complex is not given by a union of spheres, or at least I don't follow what you mean. It's given (or presented) inductively by a sequence of skeleta $\{X_n\}_{n=0, 1, 2, \ldots}$ together with, for each $n$, a family of attaching maps of the form $S^n \to X_n$ which prescribe how to form $X_{n+1}$ from $X_n$. I think what Mike is describing doesn't have much to do with CW complexes per se, but applies to any (paracompact) space $X$ with a good open cover ("good" meaning that all nonempty finite intersections of opens in the cover are contractible).

Comment: See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve+theorem

Comment: The objective is really just to compute the homology of the union of $n$-spheres where the spheres must cover a loop space. @user43208

Comment: It might be easier to discuss this offline. Google my name IRL + in nLab and you should find my email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82282/discussion-between-multivariablecalculus-and-user43208).

Comment: @user43208 Done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very interesting question, unfortunately this is not enough to know the nerve. For an explicit counterexample consider $M_1$ and $M_2$ given as the union of two circles, where the circles in $M_1$ intersect twice and the circle in $M_2$ intersect four times. The nerves are isomorphic but the homology groups are not isomorphic.

When the covering is given by open balls, in order to be able to compute homology using the nerve you need to assume strong conditions on the intersections (they should be all contractible or empty) on your cover. You need probably strong conditions here too but I can't think of a good condition right now.

Comment: Thanks @NicolasHemelsoet! I can't think of such a strong condition on intersections either. See my idea in the edit above.

Comment: The condition you want is that the n-fold intersections are all empty or contractible. Then the Cech complex of this cover (with constant sheaf Z) recovers the homology of the manifold. The general case where n-fold intersections are not contractible instead takes the form of a spectral sequence involving cohomology of the various intersections: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Čech-to-derived_functor_spectral_sequence If I remember the Cech spectral sequence is well explained in the book by Bott and Tu.

Comment: @MikeMiller : Thanks for your comment !
So you don't require anything on $k$-fold intersections for $k<n$ ?
Also when you say "Cech complex" what do you mean ? The Cech complex associated to the nerve don't compute the homology correctly here but I'm not sure what would be a correct replacement for the Cech complex here.

Comment: $n$ was meant to be an arbitrary integer, not the dimension as in the OP. My bad for terrible notation.

Comment: Hi @NicolasHemelsoet! Do you mind formalizing what Mike Miller said in your answer (i.e., in mathematical notation)?

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus I don't understand Mike Miller comment so far (and I have very limited internet connexion as well) but if I understand it sure !

Comment: @MikeMiller : thanks for the reply. I don't think I understand, let us take a single copy of $S^n$. The Cech complex associated to its nerve is $Z$ in degree 0 and the cohomology is not the cohomology of the sphere.
So given the nerve associated to this family of spheres, there should be a more complicated complex we should associate which computes correctly the cohomology, however I'm not sure I can see how to construct one it looks tricky.
Also, another trivial remark but your condition doesn't work if $n=1$.

Comment: @Nicolas I don't know what you're talking about. That is not a cover by contractible sets, whose k-fold intersections are all contractible or empty, where k varies over all naturals. I am sorry if I didn't make it clear that this is what I meant.

Comment: @MikeMiller : I agree with your first comment. However the question here was "given the abstract nerve associated to a cover of M by spheres, how to compute the homology of M only using the nerve". I don't understand how you (correct) first comment helps to the question by the OP.

Comment: It doesn't - I actually missed that you covered the case of covers by discs in your answer, or I would not have commented. It does not seem helpful to me to try to compute homology via covers of spheres, but if one ever has a cover that is not by contractible sets with contractible intersection etc, the Cech spectral sequence still makes sense, it just sucks to try to compute with.

Comment: @MikeMiller : Ok, I agree it's not helpful but it seems an interesting (but complicated) problem.

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you mind making what you wrote mathematically precise (I mean notation-wise), as I am still a little confused?

Comment: Hi NicolasHemelsoet! Are you thinking of these intersection conditions? I still don't really understand what Mike said.

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus : Mike's comment covered only the case of a cover by open balls in a more detailled way that what I wrote in my answer. I think the problem is too complicated for me so I will let the answer like this.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet In fact, I did mean balls. I apologize for this confusion.